# How do I create a Facebook application for use only on page tabs?

Tags: facebook

I'm currently creating a very basic Facebook application and I've run into a bit of a roadblock, so any help would be appreciated.

My application is as follows: I want to have the application pull records from my database that the user has added to my site off of Facebook and display them in a tab on one of their fan pages. Everything the user could add or edit will be done on my site (not on/through Facebook) so all I need to do is have my application check which page is requesting and display their records. I imagine the install will go something like this: user signs up on my site, user adds app to their page, user links their account and fan page (thinking of the best way to do this), user adds records.

The problem I'm running into is there's barely any information on the new Facebook PHP-SDK (does not use the `require_login()` method) and I'm not really sure how to start. Again, the only functionality I need on the Facebook end is for them to be able to add my application to their fan page and be able to distinguish between which page is requesting my app.

Does anyone have any resources for creating a basic application with the new SDK? Facebook's dev section is absolutely no help for beginners and I'm pulling my hair out despite a pretty solid grounding in backend development.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

tab apps have some limitations comparing to regular fb apps. You can read about those [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Tabbed_Profile).

How to make a tab - register a facebook app, fill out "Tab Name" and "Tab URL" fields in the profiles settings (you might need to fill out "canvas" settings first).

Now all tabs will be loaded from "Tab URL" on your server. How to find out who is tab owner - check for `fb_sig_profile_user` request parameter in your tab page handler, which contains owner's user id.

This should get you started.